# tkinter root.mainloop() not suitable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a big database of different astronomical objects, and I want to be able to show different information for them in a GUI. However, I am finding a big problem and don't know if there is anyway to treat it or I have to give up on the idea.

For each of these sources, there are a lot of calculations to perform before plotting anything. My idea would be to open a main GUI window, and then fo object by object:

1. first do the calculations. The information is taken from the database via mysql commands using python. At the end of this stage, I would have two or three arrays which will be plotted.
2. use the GUI to show these plots. At this stage, the user could delete some bad points by clicking using events (so the GUI should be able to communicate with the database). When some points are deleted, the plots have to be updated.
3. when the bad points are deleted, the user can click on different buttons to classify the source (lets say "star", "galaxy", "whatever").
4. once the user has clicked in any of the classification buttons, the program would jump to the next source in the database, and the process is started again.

The problem is, if I do this I have to fight with the root.mainloop() statement. Given that the calculations for the objects are complex, there is a lot of code involved and I would like SO MUCH to avoid including this code in the GUI for the sake of clarity. But otherwise, I would have to open a Tkinter window, classify one object, close it, open a new one, ... Which is time consuming and upsetting...

Is there a way to do the calculations outside the GUI part and pass the parameters to the Tkinter window without having to clear it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the calculations in a worker thread, or in a separate process.

For any single calculation, can it be performed in less than a second? If so, let the event loop work for you rather than against you. If you can put all the calculations in a list, iterator or generator somehow, you can run each calculation using `after`.

Roughly speaking, your code would look like this:

```
def do_one_calculation():

    <do the next calculation here>

    if there_are_more_calculations():
        root.after(100, do_one_calculation)
```

Depending on  how fast or slow your calculations are, you can do more or fewer every second by adjusting the first parameter to `after`. The net effect is that the calculations run "in the background", which in GUI speak means all that time when the GUI is otherwise not doing anything.